# Resistors in series to increase maximum Voltage

Tags: voltage, resistors, series, basic

Do the values of resistors matter when I want to use them in series to increase the maximum voltage they can handle?

So can I just use a 1 megohm resistor for example that's rated for 200 V and then add a 10 ohm resistor that's also rated for 200 V in series to get a maximum voltage of 400 V and then connect that to 350 V without any problems?

I tried googling it and found nothing.
Sorry if this is a stupid question.

Comment: Yes but use equal values

Answer (score 5):

> So can I just use a 1 megohm resistor for example that's rated for 200 V and then add a 10 ohm resistor that's also rated for 200 V in series to get a maximum voltage of 400 V and then connect that to 350 V without any problems?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2faRjq3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A quick look with the simulator shows the problem.*

No. The voltage dropped across across each resistor is proportional to its resistance. R1 will have 349.9965 V across it (assuming it's exactly 1 MΩ).

Answer (score 2):

> So can I just use a 1 megohm resistor for example that's rated for 200 V and then add a 10 ohm resistor that's also rated for 200 V in series to get a maximum voltage of 400 V

**No**, because if there is 400 V across 10 M Ohm + 10 Ohm (+ means in series) then there will be 399.996 V across the 10 M Ohm resistor and 4 m V across the 10 Ohm resistor.

If you want a 400 V, 1 M Ohm resistor, you need to use two 0.5 M Ohm, 200 V resistors in series.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple resistors in series to handle higher voltages than a single one can handle is a time honored practice.

Lots of high quality modern multimeters, for example, have strings of chip (SMD) resistors in series to avoid using expensive high voltage resistors.

However, the "standard" way to do it is to use equal value resistors.

I said "standard" in quotes because it's not a real rule, but it is just plain silly to build an "equivalent resistors" out of many different ones (other answers have shown the kind of calculations involved).

Moreover, since adding resistors to increase voltage rating is sensible only if they are almost the same value (otherwise those with smaller values will increase the voltage rating only in a negligible way), it would be quite stupid to build, say, a 2kohm 1000V resistor out of a 1.2khom/600V and 0.8kohm/600V resistors, when you could simply put two 1kohm/600V resistors in series.

This also simplifies *a lot* part management in high voltage designs, since you don't have to stock (or design in) a bunch of extra different parts with wildly varying R value and voltage rating.